# Reset `tikz` scale after using small mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale, zooming

I'm preparing a beamer presentation and have a complicated mindmap in it.
To make it nicely fit on the frames  I use `\tikzset{small mindmap}`.

On subsequent frames I have images with [nicely drawn scale bars](https://github.com/habi/latex/blob/master/draw_a_scalebar.py).

Setting a 'small mindmap'  messes up the placement of my scalebar label, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: messed up background]

I *think* it has something to do with setting a general zoom/scale factor in tikz.
Is there a way I can 'reset' tikz to a normal state after drawing my mindmap?
This would result in (something like) the second screenshot.

[image: intended result]

Below is the code, boiled down to nearly minimal state.
I couldn't manage to find an example image, is this not available in beamer?
The issue can be seen when commenting/uncommenting line 12 and recompiling the document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\newlength\imagewidth% needed for scalebars
\newlength\imagescale% needed for scalebars

\begin{document}

\tikzset{small mindmap}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \path[mindmap] node[concept] {Something} child {node[concept] {A}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{\linewidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/1536}%
    \def\x{949}% scalebar-x starting at golden ratio of image width of 1536px = 949
    \def\y{1335}% scalebar-y at 90% of image height of 1483px = 1335
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example−image}};
        \draw[|-|,blue,thick] (0,742) -- (1536,742) node [sloped,midway,above,fill=green,semitransparent,text opacity=1] {1536px};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Call `\tikzset{small mindmap}` in your first `tikzpicture`...

Comment: Note: `example−image` is not `example-image` (`−` is not `-`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Comment1: Thanks for the pointer, this helps. I'll move all the settings changes into the `tikzpicture`s. Comment2: I copy-pasted from `texdoc mwe` and the dashes were not copied correctly.